# SQL Query To Sort MMM-YYYY Text Data in Ascending Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [MonthYear] [NVARCHAR](8) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Current data:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
    MonthYear, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), '01-' + MonthYear, 106) AS ConvertedDate 
FROM 
    dbo.Test
ORDER BY
    ConvertedDate
```

Result of this query:

[image]

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What are you *actually* using? I suspect the latter, seeing as you reference what apepars to be the `dbo` schema.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: To answer your question, however, the data is correct. `'F'` < `'J'` and so `'Feb'` is before `'Jan'`. Store/treat your dates as a `date` and the problem goes away. This is just one reason why choosing the correct data type is so important.

Comment: That is my final option but I just want to know whether we can convert it as Standard date in query.  May-2019 should be converted as 2019-05-01

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT MonthYear,
       CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + MonthYear) as ConvertedDate
FROM dbo.Test
ORDER BY ConvertedDate;
```

SQL Server is quite good at converting strings to dates without a format.

Note:  You do not need to include the conversion in the `SELECT`, so:

```
SELECT MonthYear
FROM dbo.Test
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + MonthYear);
```

Or, you can even add this into the table:

```
ALTER TABLE Test
    ADD MonthYear_date as (CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + MonthYear));
```

You can then use `MonthYear_date` as you would any other column from the table.

Comment: Make that computed column a `PERSISTED` column and the OP could reap all the benefits; including adding it to their indexes. :)

Comment: Hmmm. About adding it as a computed column... Seems that things go terribly wrong if you put an "invalid" value in column MonthYear... INSERT query would succeed. SELECT query would fail. So personally, I wouldn't do that. ;)

Comment: @BartHofland you could use `TRY_CONVERT` then.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, if I would use such a construct, I would definitely use a fail safe mechanism like TRY_CONVERT.

Comment: @BartHofland . . . Failing with a bad value is probably a *benefit* of using a computed column.  Alas, that only appears when the column is used (unless it is persisted). The OP should probably include a check constraint anyway, to guarantee the format of the column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes. I partly agree. It's certainly good to know that values are bad. But normally I would like to know that values are bad as soon as possible (here: in the INSERT query). And not later (like in a SELECT query)... Because the checking behavior is "delayed", I am cautious with such a construction.

Answer (score 2):

`CAST` the string value to `DATE` will work

```
SELECT MonthYear, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), '01-' + MonthYear ,106) AS DATE) AS ConvertedDate 
FROM dbo.Test
ORDER BY ConvertedDate
```

Sample execution with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE (MonthYear VARCHAR (10));

INSERT INTO @TestData (MonthYear) VALUES
('May-19'), ('Jan-19'), ('Jun-19'), ('Feb-19');

SELECT MonthYear, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), '01-' + MonthYear ,106) AS DATE) AS ConvertedDate 
FROM @TestData
ORDER BY ConvertedDate
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You're converting a varchar to varchar with style = 106, then to date. It works by accident.

Answer (score 1):

use `order by convert(nvarchar,[MonthYear],101)`

```
select *, convert(nvarchar,[MonthYear],101) 
from [dbo].[Test]
order by convert(nvarchar,[MonthYear],101)
```

**output**
Jan-19
may-19

Comment: This also retrieving the same unsorted result like my query

Comment: Converting a `varchar` to an `nvarchar` won't change anything here. The style code you have is when converting a date/time data type to a string data type, or the reverse; not for when converting from one string type to another.

Comment: Also, you should really get into the habit of declaring your length, scale, precision, etc for your data types. Not doing so can (and will) end up causing you some unexpected and unwanted behaviour.